# Double ended Queue (Deque) Quicksort

Tags: java, queue, quicksort

I've been wrestling with my quicksort function for a bit but still have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

When I run quicksort on a deque containing randomly generated elements [6,92,63,90,79,94,8,13,72,28]

The result is [13,8,28,94,92,63,72,90,79,6]

```
public class DoublyLinkedDeque<E extends Comparable<E>> implements DequeADT<E>
{
    ...

    public void quickSort(DoublyLinkedDeque<E> deque, Comparator<E> comp) 
    {
        int n = deque.size();
        if (n < 2) 
        {
            return;
        }
        // using first as arbitrary pivot
        E pivot = deque.first();                     
        DoublyLinkedDeque<E> left = new DoublyLinkedDeque<>();
        DoublyLinkedDeque<E> equalsPivot = new DoublyLinkedDeque<>();
        DoublyLinkedDeque<E> right = new DoublyLinkedDeque<>();
        while (!deque.isEmpty()) 
        {
            // divide original into left, equalsPivot, and right
            E element = deque.dequeueFront();
            int tmpCompare = comp.compare(element, pivot);
            // element is less than pivot
            if (tmpCompare < 0)                             
            {
                left.enqueueFront(element);
            }
            // element is equal to pivot
            else if (tmpCompare == 0)                       
            {
                equalsPivot.enqueueFront(element);
            }
            // element is greater than pivot
            else                                   
            {
                right.enqueueFront(element);
            }
        }
        // sort elements less than pivot
        quickSort(left, comp);                      
        // sort elements greater than pivot
        quickSort(right, comp);                      
        // concatenate results
        while (!left.isEmpty())
        {
            deque.enqueueFront(left.dequeueFront());
        }
        while (!equalsPivot.isEmpty())
        {
            deque.enqueueFront(equalsPivot.dequeueFront());
        }
        while (!right.isEmpty())
        {
            deque.enqueueFront(right.dequeueFront());
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{        

    DoublyLinkedDeque<Integer> deque = new DoublyLinkedDeque<Integer>();

    /* ADDING RANDOM NUMBER TO deque */

    Comparator<Integer> intComparator = new Comparator<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2)
        {
            return (i1 < i2 ? -1 : i1 > i2 ? +1 : 0);
        }
    };

    deque.quickSort(deque, intComparator);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your code correctly, the error is in the last part, where you concatenate the results.

You start with the left part (numbers smaller than pivot), remove its first element und push it from the left into the queue, so it becomes the right-most element. Then you push the pivot, then the elements of the right part (numbers bigger than pivot), becoming the left-most elments in the queue.

For example

- left: [3]
- pivot: [5]
- right: [7]

Now concatenate (in steps)

1. left -> deque [3]
2. pivot (enqueueFront) -> deque [5,3]
3. right (enqueueFront) -> deque [7,5,3]

So lets assume this set is now the result of a left-part processing. Now if you combine that set with another ill-sorted set of bigger values (a right part) of `[9,8]`

- left: [7,5,3]
- right: [9,8]

you get (steps simplified)

1. [7]
2. [5,7]
3. [3,5,7]
4. [9,3,5,7]
5. [8,9,3,5,7]

As could be seen, the order of the partially sorted sublists alternates with each recursion. Resulting in an ill-sorted result set with partially sorted fragments.

**TL;DR** check the order of the concatenation or use a proper add operation (front vs back)